# What operations does pg_dump block?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to backup a live postgres database using pg_dump, however when ever I attempt to do so it causes things to blow up.

I have many live queries aggressively reading from a `materialized view` (it's a cache), which is aggressively refreshed (every minute or more).

I am starting to believe that pg_dump blocks the `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` from occurring, which blocks the reads from the materialized view, which causes things to explode.

Is this line of reasoning correct? What other operations does pg_dump block, and how should I do the backup?

Answer (score -1):

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) (emphasis mine):

> pg_dump does **not** block other users accessing the database (readers or writers).

Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug then? With 100% reproducibility I can cause readers to block by running pg_dump on postgres 9.3.5, and with 100% reproducibility they continue when I kill pg_dump. Just to be sure, I ran pg_dump now, and watched the application pause, again.

Comment: `pg_dump` blocks DDL operations like refresh materialized view.

Comment: "These aren't the droids you're looking for..."